# 1 Samuel 20:18: How was the First of the Month / New Moon Determined?

Tags: historical-interpretation, 1-samuel, chronology, historical-criticism, calendar

<sup>**Closely Related:**</sup>
<sup>• [Judaism.SE/How was Rosh Chodesh determined, if a New Moon Cannot be Seen?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/81563/how-was-rosh-chodesh-determined-if-a-new-moon-cannot-be-seen)</sup>
<sup>• [Calculating months and weeks in the Mosaic Law](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/13260/calculating-months-and-weeks-in-the-mosaic-law)</sup>
<sup>• [Astronomy.SE/How Soon Could a Waxing Crescent Moon Be Seen?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/14265/how-soon-could-a-waxing-crescent-moon-be-seen)</sup>

---

## 1. Question:

Apart from Rabbinical commentary, (in the Talmud) - ***is there any Scriptural or literary evidence explaining how a New Moon was determined*** - especially since it is not visible?
Or, was it the case that the Waxing Crescent Moon was taken "As and For" the New Moon?

---

## 2. The Text/Context:

> **NASB, 1 Samuel 20:18** - Then Jonathan said to him, Tomorrow is the new moon, and you will be missed because your seat will be empty.

If ***a New Moon cannot be seen***, then it seems that the first visible confirmation of a New Moon is actually the Waxing Crescent Moon, which can only be observed after the New Moon - minimally - after 12.1 hours with a telescope, and 15.5 hours without. (See [Astronomy.SE/How Soon Could a Waxing Crescent Moon Be Seen?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/14265/how-soon-could-a-waxing-crescent-moon-be-seen)).

Comment: Voted to close as off-topic because 1) the question is about a Biblical subject but does not cite a particular verse. That is, the question does not arise from the verse cited any more than any other verse such as Exodus 12:2. 2) There is an anachronistic assumption behind question that there was a need for a "method". But the need for a method only arose in later times. 3) Whatever the answer, it makes no difference for our understanding of any Biblical text.

Comment: You could ask a question about the meaning of מחר חודש. Does it imply prediction, or does it simply mean "in a while" similar to mañana in American English. There isn't any computation of time in the OT other than וספרתם לכם ממחרת השבת and similar trivial examples.

Comment: The word מחר doesn't necessarily mean "tomorrow" in this verse. And the word חדש doesn't necessarily mean "new moon". That is a common translation but it is not a necessary translation. The simple meaning of the verse can be read, "At the coming new moon feast your place will be empty and your absence will be noted". In general, there is no calculation of time, weights or measures in the MT. The notions of precision that we have today are both post OT and "off-topic" as far as the OT is concerned. Besides that, there is no evidence of a single set calendar or even a need for one in the OT.

Comment: @AbuMunirIbnIbrahim - **A.)** Given the context - I can see the answer going either direction : They knew exactly when events would occur, planning to meet in "3 days"; or : They didn't know exactly, which may be why they had "two feasts"; **B.)** Either way - your objection to the question relies on ripping "tomorrow | מחר" out of the verse, and a baseless presupposition that there are no measurements in the OT(???); **C.)** Regardless, even if you are right - an explanation is merited rather than a dismissive unsubstantiated declaration; **D.)** Your comments are better suited as an answer.

Comment: I think that the correct question to ask is "Does I Sam 20:18 imply that Jonathan knew when the new moon would be, and if so, how would he know?". I think that you should ask that question and close this one.

Comment: related: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/35457/why-did-they-celebrate-again-the-day-after-the-new-moon-in-1-samuel-2027?rq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why did they celebrate again the day after the New Moon in 1 Samuel 20:27?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/35457/why-did-they-celebrate-again-the-day-after-the-new-moon-in-1-samuel-2027)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Genesis 1:14** Then God said, “Let there be lights in the expanse of the
> heavens to separate the day from the night, and **they shall serve as
> signs and for seasons, and for days** and years;
>
> **Psalm 104:19** He made **the moon for the seasons**; The sun knows the place
> of its setting.

When the New Moon occurred seems to have been totally natural to determine and non of the prophets that is mentioning New Moon as Moses, Samuel, Ezra, Nehemiah, Isiah, Ezekiel, Hosea & Amos even tell us how it is done, the answer might be found in Jubilees that state that; "1:13-14 *I will hide My face from them. I will deliver them into the hand of the Gentiles. They will be captured like prey for their eating. I will remove them from the land. I will scatter them among the Gentiles. 14 And they will forget My law and all My commandments and all My judgments. **They will go astray regarding the observance of new months**, and sabbaths, and festivals, and jubilees, and laws*."

### The Book of Jubilees

**INTRODUCTION**
This is the history of how the days were
divided and of the days of the law and of the
testimony, of the events of the years, and of
the weeks of years, of their Jubilees
throughout all the years of the world, as Yah
spoke to Moses on Mount Sinai when he went
up to receive the tablets of the law and the
commandment, according to the voice of
Elohim when he said to him, “Go up to the
top of the Mount.”

**Chapter 1:7-17**
Write all these words for yourself which I
speak to you today, for I know their rebellion
and their stubbornness, before I brought them
into the land of which I swore to their fathers,
to Abraham and to Isaac and to Jacob, saying,
“Unto your offspring will I give a land flowing
with milk and honey.
8
They will eat and be satisfied, and they will
turn to strange deities, to deities that cannot
deliver them from any of their tribulation, and
this witness shall be heard for a witness against
them.
9
They will forget all My commandments, even
all that I command them, and they will walk in
the ways of the Gentiles, and after their
uncleanness, and after their shame, and will
serve their deities, and these will prove to
them an offence and a tribulation and an
sickness and a trap.
10 Many will perish and they will be taken
captive, and will fall into the hands of the
enemy, because they have forsaken My laws
and My commandments, and the festivals of
My covenant, and My sabbaths, and My pure
place which I have made pure for Myself in
their presence, and My tabernacle, and My
sanctuary, which I have made pure for Myself
in the midst of the land, that I should set My
name on it, that it should reside there.
11 They will make themselves high places and
places of worship and graven images. Each will
worship graven images of his own making,
Thus they will go astray. They will sacrifice
their children to demons, and to all errors
their hearts can work.
12 I will send witnesses to them that I may
testify against them, but they will not hear.
They will kill the witnesses. They will
persecute those who seek the law, and they will
abolish and change everything (in the Law) so
as to work evil before My eyes.
13 I will hide My face from them. I will deliver
them into the hand of the Gentiles. They will
be captured like prey for their eating. I will
remove them from the land. I will scatter them
among the Gentiles.
14 **And they will forget My law and all My
commandments and all My judgments. They
will go astray regarding the observance of new
months, and sabbaths, and festivals, and
jubilees, and laws**.
15 After this they will turn to Me from among
the Gentiles with all their heart and with all
their soul and with all their strength, and I will
gather them from among all the Gentiles, and
they will seek me. I shall be found by them
when they seek me with all their heart and
with all their soul.
16 I will allow them to see abounding peace
with righteousness. I will remove them, the
plant of uprightness, with all My heart and
with all My soul, and they shall be for a
blessing and not for a curse, and they shall be
the head and not the tail.
17 I will build My sanctuary among them, and I
will dwell with them, and I will be their
Elohim and they shall be My people in truth
and righteousness.

**Chapter 2:13-14** I will hide My face from them. I will deliver
them into the hand of the Gentiles. They will
be captured like prey for their eating. I will
remove them from the land. I will scatter them
among the Gentiles.
14 And they will forget My law and all My
commandments and all My judgments. **They
will go astray regarding the observance of new
months**, and sabbaths, and festivals, and
jubilees, and laws.

**Chapter 6:32-38** Command you the children of Israel that
they observe the years according to this
counting, three hundred and sixty-four days,
and these will constitute a complete year, and
they will not disturb its time from its days and
from its feasts; for every thing will fall out in
them according to their testimony, and they
will not leave out any day nor disturb any
feasts. 33 But if they neglect and do not observe them
according to His commandment, then they
will disturb all their seasons and the years will
be dislodged from this order, and they will
neglect their established rules.
34 And **all the children of Israel will forget and
will not find the path of the years, and will
forget the new months**, and seasons, and
sabbaths and they will wrongly determine all
the order of the years. 35 For I know and from now on will I declare it
to you, and it is not of my own devising; for
the book lies written in the presence of me,
and on the heavenly tablets the division of
days is ordained, or they forget the feasts of the
covenant and walk according to the feasts of
the Gentiles after their error and after their
ignorance. 36 For there will be those who will assuredly
make observations of the moon and how it
disturbs the seasons and comes in from year to
year ten days too soon. For this reason I command and testify to
you that you may testify to them; for after
your death your children will disturb them, so
that they will not make the year three hundred
and sixty-four days only, and for this reason
**they will go wrong as to the new months** and
seasons and sabbaths and festivals, and they
will eat all kinds of blood with all kinds of
flesh.

[Jubilees PDF](https://static1.squarespace.com/static/58535279e3df28f58aa0db40/t/5ef7bc8927513553d32a163e/1593293988385/Jubilees.pdf)

---

In **Leviticus 23** all expect The New Moon is mentioned;

Lev 23:2 Yah's appointed times which you shall proclaim as set apart convocations—My appointed times are these: **The Sabbath** (Lev. 23:3) **The Passover** (23:5) **The Feast of Unleavened bread** (23:6-8) **The Feast of First fruits** (23:10-14) **The Feast of Weeks** (23:15-22) **The Feast of Trumpets** (23:24-25) **the Day of Atonement** (23:27-32) **The Feast of Tabernacles** (23:35-37).

Just as if it was to be a hidden day, concealed, veiled for a period of time until The New Moon ones again will be observed (Colossians 2:16-17, Isaiah 66:23, Ezekiel 45:17, 46:1-6).

Comment: Your statement that even the prophets didn't clarify this lends to a "common-sense" definition, (taken for granted), and probably evidence that they didn't think it needed to be clarified.  But, there were a lot of changes to "tradition", (in my opinion), caused by Babylonian influence—so there may have been a change.  **But,** your citations from  Jubiliees, (and if I recall correctly, Ezekiel as well, that this is lost information does serve as an answer, (at least a moot/unknowable answer).  So, I have chosen to accept this until someone offers a quantifiable source/reference. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am unaware of any Biblical text that explicitly answers this question, but we can answer what was done in practice: a new moon was recognized at the first sliver of the waxing crescent (see discussion by Ben Dreyfus [here](https://reformjudaism.org/passover-7-or-8-days)).

As noted in the first link you cited, this was done by the Jews by observation until the 4th century, and by calculation thereafter.

Because a true lunar month is approx. 29.5 days, an observed lunar month would last either 29 or 30 days. That the beginning of the month was determined by observation in Biblical times did not mean they didn't know when the new moon would be--they could always narrow it down to one of two possible dates (+29 or +30 from the last new moon). So it's not at all unrealistic that Jonathan would know the new moon was coming.

In fairness to the ancient astronomers, they spent a lot more time looking at the heavens than most of us do, so while error is possible in an observed system, I suggest we give them the benefit of the doubt (in the absence of conflicting evidence) that they knew what they were doing--they saw a waxing crescent (though not quite as quickly as it could have been seen with a telescope) and validated the beginning of a new month.

Answer (score 0):

The conjunction is the darken moon the Evening before the New Moon. This was the sign seen between the end and the beginning of a new Month.
My take is that there was total darkness before the light  in the beginning 6 days of creation. Surely we at least can understand that much. So is that where the answers are? I feel we can trust Jubilees as I feel it is worthy in my heart.

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics, Annette.  This site is different to many others and you might want to take our Tour to see what we look for in answers: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).